# Installing Bluetooth

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, bluetooth

The last update removed my bluetooth driver. How do I re-install it?

Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 6.2.0-26-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × AMD Ryzen 9 6900HX with Radeon Graphics
Memory: 13.4 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: REMBRANDT

This method did not work > https://www.howtogeek.com/829360/how-to-set-up-bluetooth-on-linux/

When I try to run blueman-manager I get "Bluez daemon is not running, blueman-manager cannot continue. This probably means that there were no Bluetooth adapters detected or Bluetoogh daemon was not started.
I tried this:sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
○ bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
Loaded: error (Reason: Unit bluetooth.service failed to load proper>
Active: inactive (dead)
Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Aug 26 08:38:22 vance-UM690 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Two services >
Aug 26 09:04:34 vance-UM690 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Two services >
Aug 26 09:04:42 vance-UM690 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Two services >
Aug 26 09:20:02 vance-UM690 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Two services >
lines 1-9/9 (END)

How do I roll back the blueman-manager update so my bluetooth will work again?

Comment: When I try to run blueman-manager I get "Bluez daemon is not running, blueman-manager cannot continue. This probably means that there were no Bluetooth adapters detected or Bluetoogh daemon was not started.

Comment: Edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'`